# Should I check the network status before performing network operations?

Tags: android, android-permissions

My app is using the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to download data from the network, so it asks for the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission.

Should I also check if the device is connected to a network (through [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) and [NetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html)) thus adding [ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) to the requested permission, or should I simply try to download the data and handle the exception?

Both Google's [Connecting to the Network](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) and [Managing Network Usage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html) guides recommends to the developer to check the network status before trying to do network operations for "better user experience", but I remember reading a tutorial (which I'm not able to find at the moment) telling to ask only for really unavoidable permissions to not scare users away and for a better "self-control".

So,

- Is there some kind of best practice regarding this?
- Are there any kind of problems with not asking the permission and handling the exception?

Comment: My opinion is that you should only add the extra permission if you want to *do* something when it changes, or if you want to *change* something depending on state. For instance, if you want to disable a feature when network isn't present(rather than notifying when attempted). Otherwise it's just an extra permission to "scare" people, as you said. Just my opinion, though, and I'm sure that others may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you check for network availability before doing calls to remote services, you still need to handle the case connection fails during conversation. It takes few seconds to download few hundred kB over 2G after all and you can be disconnected at any time (user could even interrupt you by going into flight mode).

Just make it nice to the user. Show them errors in a nonintrusive way.